# Is using Python modules main function for validation testing a bad idea?

Tags: python, module, batch-file, program-entry-point

I'll quickly explain exactly what I mean by this.

I'm working on a project using python, where I have multiple modules doing segments of work. Let's say for example I have a module called `Parser.py` and this module has a function `parseFile()` which my main module `Main.py` calls in order to parse some files.

As of right now, I'm using a main method inside of the Parser.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    line_list = parseFile(sys.argv[1])

    out_file = open(sys.argv[2], "w")
    for i in range(len(line_list)):
        out_file.write(line_list[i].get_string(True))
```

It's not important what exactly the parsing does, but the important part is if you call it, the first argument will be the input file for the parsing, the second argument is the output file for parsing.

So, what I'm doing essentially, is I'm using a batch file to validate the results of my parser by a typical input, output, baseline system...

```
ECHO Set the test, source, input, output and baseline directories
set TESTDIR=%CD%
set SRCDIR=%CD%\..\pypro\src
set INDIR=%CD%\input
set OUTDIR=%CD%\output
set BASEDIR=%CD%\baseline


:: Parser.py main method is base for unit testing on parsing
ECHO Begin Parser testing
cd %INDIR%\Parser
FOR %%G IN (*.psma) DO %SRCDIR%\Parser.py %%G %OUTDIR%\Parser\%%G
ECHO Parser testing complete

cd %TESTDIR%

"C:\Program Files\WinMerge\winmergeU.exe" "%OUTDIR%"  "%BASEDIR%"
```

As you can see it diffs the results against the baseline, so if anything is changed the programmer knows it is no longer valid, or the requirements are wrong.

Is there anything wrong with this method? I did it because it would be easy. My plan is to continue doing this with as many modules that I can which are valid and make sense to do this way, as well as a suite of pyunit tests inside pydev...

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a good idea, and it does seem to be a common use case for `if __name__ == '__main__'` construct.  Though this is a more usual structure:

```
def main(argv=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv
    # etc.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main() or 0)
```

This gives you the additional flexibility to use your `main` from within the interactive interpreter.  There are a few more nice examples from Guido and others [here](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=106&thread=4829&start=15&msRange=15).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, what I do in these situations is creating test cases (although these would could more as integration test cases and not only unit test cases).

So, usually (in my workflow), those would be regular test cases (which diff the actual output with the expected output). Although probably in a separate source folder which is not run as often as the unit-test cases.

The bad part of having it as the `__main__` is that you'll have to remember to run it as the entry point and you'll probably forget to do it later on as the project grows and you have many of those files -- or at least have a test case that calls that main() :)